# Will this kind of code always work?

Tags: jquery, dom

```
$('#container').append('<div id="theonly">tests</div>').find('#theonly');
```

and

```
$('#container').html('<div id="theonly">tests</div>').find('#theonly');
```

I'm worried sometimes the dynamically generated elements is not available at once,am I wrong or not?

If I'm not wrong,what's the solution to cover all cases?

**EDIT**
Can someone come up with a definite and unified answer?

Answer (score 2):

In the world of DOM, anyone who answers this question with "yes" is insane.

The `html(val)` function replaces `innerHTML` directly, so in theory this code should always work, since `#container` will in fact have the new html code by the time you call `find()`

However, DOM is notorious for behaving differently across different browsers. So the lesson here is to test thoroughly.

**EDIT**:
In response to "what is your solution?"

As I said above, you should thoroughly test. The function *should* work as expected, but you can never be sure without testing the major browsers.

With that said, if you really want a concrete confirmation that the new HTML is ready for querying, you can set up a poll that checks the current `html()` against the html you want to set in the first place.

Something like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.htmlX = function (html, callback) {
        var element = this;
        var poll = function () {
            if (element.html() === html) {
                callback();
            } else {
                setTimeout(poll, 100);
            }
        };

        element.html(html);
        poll();
    };

    $('#container').htmlX('<div id="theonly">tests</div>', function() { $('#container').find('#theonly').css('color', '#f00'); });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: But I seldom see code like this.Are people all ignoring this corner case?

Comment: I imagine people tested the major browsers they were targeting and found their was no issue. That is the correct solution, like I said before.

Comment: ok your solution is probably bulletproof. But i think you guys are a bit paranoïd: the jquery chaining has always proved 100% reliable to me. Except of course in extreme situations (hardware failure of some sort, using internet explorer 1, etc.). I'd be happy to be proven wrong.